# Monitoring files added to windows explorer default zip file(Compressed (Zipped) Folder)

Tags: c++, windows, hook, explorer

I need to monitor the files being added to a zip file(zip file which is opened by default explorer) through clipboard and drag/drop operations.
I tried the `dragdrophandler` approach but it helps only for clipboard and drag/drop operations happening within the explorer. Other than that the default zip files don't work (e.g. If I copy a file and paste it into the zip file which is opened by default windows explorer).
I also tried hooking the `zipfldr.dll` (`DllGetclassObject` method and `IClassfactory` interface ) but I can't get the full path of the file which is added.